# Error when displaying a ContactItem from a custom Form event in Outlook 2007

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, outlook-2007

I am developping an Outlook 2007 Add-In.

I have designed a Windows Form allowing to display operations the Add-In performs. The form is displayed modally.

In this form, I have 2 buttons, one to open an inspector on a mail item, the other to open an inspector on a contact item.

The "Show Mail" button behaves nicely, but the "Show Contact" always raises an exception saying that there is a dialog box open and I should close it before opening the contact inspector.

As the code for these 2 buttons is exactly the same, what would be the problem with the contact item inspector?

```
private void btnShowMail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    logEvent.MailItem.Display(true);
}

private void btnShowContact_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    logEvent.ContactItem.Display(true);
}
```

If the problem is that my Form is open, I don't see how to work around.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, I found that method ContactItem.Display is in colision with your form (If your form is a modal dialog)

Workaround: 
If you are opening your form like:

```
myForm.ShowDialog();
```

change it to:

```
myForm.Show();
```

I know - thats not a good solution, but I didnt found better. :-(